# How to make an OS X window span across two monitors in Mavericks/OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

Is there a way to resize a window (like Terminal.app) such that it will span multiple monitors on OS X 10.9? This was possible in earlier versions of OS X, and I'm missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into System Preferences and open up the Mission Control panel, there's a checkbox labelled "Displays have separate Spaces". If you uncheck this, you can open a window that spans multiple monitors at once, but do note that all multiple monitor support will revert to the pre-Mavericks behavior as well.